# ReactJS Firebase Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I have this code. The console.log part works and logs out the correct value of "temp". However, I cannot seem to get this value into the state. I have tried many variations. The below variation results in the error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined.

```
componentDidMount () {
  this.removeListener = firebaseAuth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
      ref.child(`users/CF0IRqCsXmMHaF5GV7uVF6XNOO33`)
        .once('value')
        .then(function(snapshot){
          console.log(snapshot.val().info.temp);
          this.setState({
            temp: snapshot.val().info.temp
          })
        });

    }
  }
}
```

I have tried adding a bind this at the end but it just won't work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the `this` you are using is not the react component. Because you are using the `function(snapshot){` syntax as part of the promise callback, the binding of `this` is lost.

Try changing `function (snapshot) {` to `(snapshot) => {`, since the fat arrow syntax will bind `this` for you.

Comment: Thank you! So I have done that (see below code), now my state does not change though but it all compiles.    ref.child(`users/CF0IRqCsXmMHaF5GV7uVF6XNOO33`).once('value').then((snapshot) => {
   console.log(snapshot.val().info.temp);

  this.setState({
    temp: snapshot.val().info.temp
  })

 })